# Angular-5 : hide gridlines of excel file using sheetJS and apply cell style

Tags: excel, angular, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to export customize excel file using sheetJS in Angular-5, but facing two problems can anybody help me to resolve these issues.
Thanks

> - how to hide/remove gridlines in workbook sheets
> - cell style not applying like font size, color etc.

Here is the code to export file which

```
export class AppComponent {

  jsonData: any = [];

  export(): void {
    /* generate worksheet */
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.jsonData);

    // add style (but not working) and value to A1 cell
    ws['A1'] = {
      v: 'AI cell value',
      s: {
        font: { size: 20, bold: true, color: "#FF00FF" },
        "!merges": [
          { s: { r: 0 } } /* A1 */
        ]
      }
    };

    /* generate workbook and add the worksheet */
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

    /* save to file */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "demo.xlsx");
  }
}
```

**Here is desired excel file format**

[image: Desired Excel File Image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide gridlines in excel, but adding a background color will make them invisible unless an outline is set. Adding this to your script will do the trick:

```
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
```

- Replace 37 with the indexed value o the color you're looking for.
  White is 2.
- Replace A1 with the visible range of your sheet (i.e., "A1:ZZ999").

Good luck!